# ngx-bootstrap date picker Non Editable | Angular 8

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

How can I make my ngx-bootstrap date picker Non-Editable?

Scenario:- Input field is editable, we can erase the date and write text,numbers.. etc

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<inputb type="text" 
placeholder="Daterangepicker"
bsDaterangepicker
formControlName="dateRange"
[maxDate]="currentDate"
name="datepicker"
[bsConfig]="{ rangeInputFormat: 'YYY-MM-DD'}">
</form>
```

[please visit screenshot for more clearification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO7pY.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<inputb type="text" 
placeholder="Daterangepicker"
bsDaterangepicker
formControlName="dateRange"
[maxDate]="currentDate"
name="datepicker"
[readonly]="!editable"
[bsConfig]="{ rangeInputFormat: 'YYY-MM-DD'}">
</form>
```